# How to know when the keyboard hides?

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextfield

I want to know when my keyboard will hide, to scroll to the top of my view.

When I use textFieldDidEndEditing, it does work when I don't edit the text field content but doesn't otherwise.

Thanks for your advices

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an observer like this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) name:UIKeyboardDidHideNotification object:nil];
```

Process the event like this:

```
- (void)keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification *)notification {
    NSLog(@"Keyboard did hide");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` to find out when the keyboard will hide. There are other notifications for DidHide, WillShow, and WillHide. You can make your UI changes in response to these notifications, rather than watching for changes only from the text field.

Apple has [documentation on how to respond to keyboard events](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW3) that you should also take a look at.

Comment: Careful: This does not fire if the keyboard was a split keyboard on an iPad (`keyboardDid/WillShow` also don't fire for split keyboards).

Answer (score 1):

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

> Return Value
>
> YES if the text field should implement its default behavior for the return button; otherwise, NO.

In order to actually hide the keyboard, you need to call

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
```